# Visual Studio 2010 going crazy with silverlight projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, silverlight

I tried to create a new Silverlight project in Visual Studio 2010 (Ultimate version) for the first time.

It told me I got to install the latest version of Silverlight, before creating any.

```
You need to install the latest silverlight developer runtime before creating a silverlight project
```

I clicked the link on the message, download and install whatever was there.

Then when I tried to create a new project, it told me I got to install "Silverlight 3 sdk".

I removed the new version, and installed Silverlight 3 sdk.

Then again, when I tried to create a new project I recived the error stating I must install the latest version.

It went like this a bit more, then after searching on the internet, I removed everything from my computer with "Silverlight" in it's name, installed Visual Studio SP 1, reinstalled Silverlight 5 (this time I paid attention to install x64 version, since it turns out that in the error message Microsoft supplied a link to x86 version, no matter what OS you are running).

I managed to create a new project, and everything was fine.

Then I downloaded some Silverlight.FX samples (probably for version 3).

They weren't open properly (which was a downer by itself), and then I recieved again a message tells me I must istall the newest version.

I closed Visual Studio, tried to create a new project, and got again the same message.

It seems the problem reappeared just because I opened an old project.

Does it make sense? Why my Visual Studio is so unstable? What should I do?

Comment: [web platform installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) can sometimes help to deal with the various Visual Studio addon like this. It will detect automatically, applicable downloads and silently install everything needed.

Comment: Do you have any idea why opening the sample project made my this behavior?

Comment: Why did I got a down vote? I made much effort before posting, and within the post..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your silverlight plugin version, silverlight sdk and silverlight developer tools version should be same version. Please check this.